# Enum reference argument transfer instead of int reference argument

Tags: c++, reference, enums

I have the following code :

```
typedef enum {Z,O,T} num;
bool toInt (str s,int& n);//<-if convert is possible converts s to integer ,puts the result in n and returns true,else returns false
```

I want to use `toInt` function and transfer as a second argument ,argument of type num 
num n;
toInt("2",n);
This causes compilation error.

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'num' to 'int &'
```

I tried to use a cast : `toInt("2",(num)n);` But it is still problematic
How can I solve the issue?

Comment: What is the compiler error? We can't help you if you don't tell us.

Comment: It's still fairly vague but it's probably because you need a cast.

Comment: I meant inside the body of the function where the parameter is being used. Except you didn't post your function body so how could I know?

Comment: -1: The function name is misleading. It should return int, and the matching to enum should be done outside / in other (properly named) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of type `num` isn't an `int`, so it has to be converted to a temporary `int` before it is passed to the function. Tempories cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

---

*If* you want to convert via an `int`, you will have to convert in two steps:

```
int temp;
toInt("2", temp);
num n = static_cast<num>(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggested, you add a new enum type for signaing invalid enum e.g:

```
enum num {Z,O,T,Invalid=4711} ;//no need to use typedef in C++
```

and change the signature to num instead of int:

```
bool toInt (str s, num& n)
{
 if ( s=="Z" ) n=Z; 
 else if ( s=="O" ) n=O;
 else if ( s=="T" ) n=T;
 else { n=Invalid; return false; }
 return true;
}
```

regards